# How to remove App store connect "tv OS App 1.0 prepare for submission"?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

In app store connect , i mistakenly clicked on "Add tv OS App" and it created "tvOS App 1.0 prepare for submission" and also clicked on "Add Mac OS App" and it created "Mac OS App 1.0 prepare for submission". "Account Holder" can able to remove "Mac OS App 1.0 prepare for submission" but cannot able to remove "tvOS App 1.0 prepare for submission". why is not happening and What should i do to remove this "tvOS App 1.0 prepare for submission"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just click on the tvOS 1.0 icon on the left side of AppStore connect and hover your mouse. When the delete icon appears, click it

Comment: Yes, when i hover the mouse i am getting delete icon only for MacOS 1.0 but i am not getting for tv OS 1.0